# I can't get out of the iframe inside iframe using watir-webdriver

Tags: webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir-webdriver to do multi-browser front-end automation test. Here I got a question. When the driver go into the first iframe of the page, it can get out, to find elements outside iframe, but if driver go into the iframe inside one iframe of the page, it can not go out and find the element of the outside page. the structure may look like this:

the main page:

```
<div>
<iframe src='a.html'></iframe>
</div>
```

a.html:

```
<div>
<iframe src='b.html'></iframe>
</div>
```

when web driver go into the b.html, and find elements in it, it can not get back to the main page.

Is anyone familiar with watir-webdriver can figure this out??

Thanks so much!

Comment: Show us your Watir code.

Answer (score 0):

To change focus back to main page from an iframe:

`@browser.frame(:index, 0).locate`